# troubles with connection to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When I start site from visual studio(F5) - it works normal in browser. 
But when I start it from IIS Manager - it always shows standart IIS page with languages.

Site uses database DB.mdf. In web config connection string is

`Data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2;Database=DB;Integrated security=true`

The database is in App_Data.

In IIS manager  in ASP.NET->Connectionstring for my site I've create new connectionstring - same as the connection string in web.config with name CName.

Where is a problem? The path to my site is the path to catalog which contains App_Data catalog.

Comment: If you're getting the default IIS page isn't the issue one of sorting out the pathing config of the site in IIS rather than a DB access issue? (not saying you won't have an issue there too).

Comment: But I don't see any error with paths. They all are correct I think.

Answer (score 1):

When running in IIS, it uses the security context of the Application Pool it's running under.  You will either need to use a different user on your App Pool Identity, or grant rights to your resources to the current App Pool user.

See [this article on how to setup the App Pool identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).